# openfig function unavailable in octave?

Tags: function, octave

I was trying to the following line in octave as part of a GUI plot program.

```
if nargin == 0 
  warning off
  fig = openfig(mfilename,'reuse');
  warning on
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
error: 'openfig' undefined near line xx
```

Is this function not available in octave? How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried posting this as a comment but it messed up the formatting, so posting as an answer instead, though its really more of a comment.

I can't replicate your error. If I run the following script to save 'Unitled.fig':

```
x = linspace (0, 2*pi, 200);
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y);
savefig(gcf);
```

and then run:

```
n = 0;
mfilename = 'Untitled'
if n == 0 
    warning off
    fig = openfig(mfilename,'reuse');
    warning on
endif
```

it works fine on my machine using Octave 5.2.0, though the 'reuse' option isn't mentioned in the Octave manual. Maybe the file you are trying to open is an incompatible format? Was it originally saved using Matlab?